# Цикл for и список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать, так, чтобы список выводился так:

1: 5 Колбаса

2: 6 Хлеб

Но у меня получается:

1: 5 Колбаса

2: 5 Колбаса

1: 6 Хлеб

2: 6 Хлеб

```
inventory = ["5 Колбаса", "6 Хлеб"]

b = len(inventory) + 1
for i in inventory:
  for a in range(1, b):
    print(str(a) + ":", i)
```

Comment: два цикла - два вывода на каждый элемент. Должен быть один цикл.

Comment: Вы делаете вложенный цикл, вот у вас и получается двойной вывод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def some_print():
    inventory = ["5 Колбаса", "6 Хлеб"]

    for index, item in enumerate(inventory, start=1):
        print(f'{index}: {item}')


some_print()
```

Вывод

```
1: 5 Колбаса
2: 6 Хлеб
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ["5 Колбаса", "6 Хлеб"]
b =[f"{i}: {x}" for i, x in enumerate(a, 1)]
print(*b, sep='\n')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]